# Accessing data in vector creates EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c++, objective-c

I try to access/print data from a vector3f which results in `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`:

```
std::cout << myMesh.faces[1].vertices[1].pos.x;
```

Code:

```
struct Vector2f{
    float x, y;
};
struct Vector3f{
    float x, y, z;
};

struct ObjMeshVertex{
    Vector3f pos;
    Vector2f texcoord;
    Vector3f normal;
};

struct ObjMeshFace{
    ObjMeshVertex vertices[3];
    ObjMeshFace(){}
    ObjMeshFace(const ObjMeshFace& o)
    {for (int i=0; i < 3; ++i) vertices[i] = o.vertices[i]; }
};

struct ObjMesh{
    std::vector<ObjMeshFace> faces;
};

ObjMesh myMesh;

for(size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); ++i){
    ObjMeshFace face;
    for(size_t j = 0; j < 3; ++j){
        face.vertices[j].pos        = positions[(faces[i].pos_index[j] - 1)];
        face.vertices[j].texcoord   = texcoords[faces[i].tex_index[j] - 1];
        face.vertices[j].normal     = normals[faces[i].nor_index[j] - 1];
    }
    myMesh.faces.push_back(face);
}
```

The debugger refers to `stl_vector.h`:

```
  reference
  operator[](size_type __n)
  { return *(this->_M_impl._M_start + __n); }
```

What does this mean? Am i calling out of range?

Comment: have you pushed anything into faces ? seems like it is still empty.

Comment: @AndersK, theres data in faces, im using this to render OpenGL and everything works as it should. I just cant access it this way for some reason.

Comment: Let's see all the code - a minimal compilable example is best - as we can't see how you call your objects and how hey were set up _+ as said please tag usefully as Xcode is usually Objective C

Comment: @Mark, i added more code to show how i populate with data. As mentioned in another comment to AndersK this is functional code i am using for rendering purposes.

Comment: @Mark, in the `struct ObjMesh`

Comment: So the code in the for loop will never get executed as faces.size() == 0 - so where does you code crash?

Comment: Since it's std::vector that is giving you the problem try rewriting the item access with at() so it will throw ASAP. `faces.at(i).pos_index[j]`

Comment: @MarkThalman, can you please give an example? Im not use to working with exception handling in CPP.

Comment: @Mark, i think your misunderstanding my question. As mentioned my code is full functional, although im making an extension to my code and the first line of code i added is generating this error. So to answer your observation faces.size is > 0.

Comment: Rewrite the access the way I did in all three lines, then run it. It should crash on the first access violation with the PC on the offending line. If that doesn't work you could tell Xcode to stop on all C++ throw() calls.

Comment: @MarkThalman, i tried to add it everywhere i had such call but it still ends up in the `stl_vector.h` file.

Comment: Do you have a good stack trace when it crashes? What is the value of i? j?

Comment: @MarkThalman, as you can see i have set the positions to 1 and 1 in the first code line that crashes. I know these positions are populated with data. My stracktrace only outputs this line which i could see being handy `0 std::vector<ObjMeshFace, std::allocator<ObjMeshFace> >::operator[](unsigned long)` but its out of my scope of interpretating.

Comment: Then what is myMesh.faces.size()?

Comment: This is a stab in the dark but are any of your objects allocated on the heap ? Could you post a bit more code concerning your extension, showing the function calls ?

Comment: Unless you want to see OpenGL code i dont have anything else beyond this? But i can supply that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while, but when you do a push_back you are only shallow copying the vertices array `vertices[] = vertices[]`. You need a custom copy-ctor in ObjMeshFace.  That's why `vertices[0].pos.x` works and `vertices[1].pos.x` doesn't.

Comment: when you do a push_back on your vector you are placing a copy of your object on that vector. Vector2f, Vector3f, all copy nicely since they are made up of simple objects but in C/C++ you cannot copy an array by simply saying a[] = b[]. If you say a[] = b[], you are only copying the pointer. So to push_back an entire ObjMeshFace object you can add a CopyContructor (method) that push_back will automatically call, from there you can copy the array index by index.

Comment: That makes alot more sense. Since its working code and i dont want to mess up anything, is there a way to make a workaround?

Comment: Since there's a problem you've got to change something. It's really simple. In `struct ObjMeshFace` just add `ObjMeshFace(const ObjMeshFace& o){for int i=0; i < 3; ++i) vertices[i] = o.vertices[i]; }` other than that I can't think of much.

Comment: The code had some brackets missing so i corrected it to `ObjMeshFace(const ObjMeshFace& o) {for (int i=0; i < 3; ++i) vertices[i] = o.vertices[i]; }`, which did not work.. Due to `No matching constructor for initialization of 'ObjMeshFace'`

Comment: my apologies, when you do that c++ requires that you add a default constructor as well; the method that is called when the object is created. Here you can initialize your array or you'll probably just want to add the following bogus default constructor `ObjMeshFace(){}`

Comment: please see my primary post where i have updated the code. Unfortunately i get same error..